# How to eliminate the default left and right white space use by APS.NET layout file?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

[image]

I suspect that is the Bootstrap 5 default setting. I used the inspection to find that there indeed is BS wrapper class, I used the CSS to set all margin and padding of the `div.container` to 0px, however, the situation become worse, the whole section was shifted to the left and a weird margin occurs at right. Any clue?

```
div.container{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the wrapper that combines the template and existing HTML code. Change `container` to `container-fluid` of the wrapper will solve the problem.

in the jQuery file add:

`$('.container').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container');`